# Python RegEx: find specific word followed by roman numeral

Tags: python, regex

I've been trying lots and lots of patterns, but I have to face the fact that regex and I don't get along too well.

My problem is this: I have to find whether a string contains a specific word followed by an unknown number of spaces followed by roman numeral.

I have tried this on the regex101 website and it works just fine:

```
"\b((chapter|chap\.)[\s]+[IVXLCDM]+\b)"
```

But still, for some mysterious reason, it doesn't work on my shell nor code (python 3.5.1):

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("\b((chapter|chap\.)[\s]+[IVXLCDM]+\b)", re.IGNORECASE)
test = "this is Chapter I bla bla"
re.findall(pattern, test)
>>>[]
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Use a raw string literal. `r"\b((chapter|chap\.)[\s]+[IVXLCDM]+\b)"`

Comment: Great, it worked! Thanks